# Python ImportError- what is wrong here?

Tags: python, import, module, importerror

I am new to programming and Python. I am following the *Learn Python the Hard Way* book.
As a part of exercise 25, I wrote a script:

```
def break_words(stuff):   
    """This function will break up words for us."""   
    words = stuff.split(' ')    
    return words        

def sort_words(words):    
    """Sorts the words."""    
    return sorted(words)        

def print_first_word(words):    
    """Prints the first words after popping it off."""    
    word = words.pop(0)    
    print word
        
def print_last_word(words):    
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""    
    word = words.pop(-1)    
    print word    
    
def sort_sentence(sentence):    
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""    
    words = break_words(sentence)    
    return sort_words(words)       

def print_first_and_last(sentence):    
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""    
    words = break_words(sentence)    
    print_first_word(words)`
```

I saved this from gedit as

> ex25.py

under the path

> C:\Users\Brandon\Experiment\Python_ex

I am running 64-bit Windows 7.

When I go to import ex25 from python.exe
I get:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "(stdin)", line 1, in `<module>`
> ImportError: No module named ex25
```

Under Computer\Properties\Advanced\Environment Variables I added the System Variable:

> PYTHONPATH
>
> C:\Python27

That didn't help.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C:\Users\Brandon\Experiment\Python_ex` is not on your system path, thus python is not aware where your `ex25` module can be found

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Brandon\Experiment\Python_ex')
```

Comment: I get:  NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: Can't be true. [`sys`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) is a part of [`Python Standard Library`](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) and always "importable"

Comment: I had not imported sys yet. Thank you so much! You have provided my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. As my file was saved in Desktop/mint/ex25.py . I first changed the directory to desktop by command cd Desktop/mint. and than run the way it has been recommended. It will solve it.
Want to go back to older directory use command cd -.