# "ImportError: cannot import name" with fresh Anaconda install

Tags: python, anaconda

I am receiving the following error in an iPython notebook:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-06ac68ebf148> in <module>()
      5 import pandas as pd
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 from sklearn import neighbours
      8 
      9 start_time = time.time()

ImportError: cannot import name neighbours
```

Whilst trying to run the following:

```
# Import required packages
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import neighbours
```

I get the same issue on the command line. My suspicions:

- I believe my problem has something to do with my system path or environment variables. I've given this various attempts and have followed other answers (e.g. [Python ImportError- what is wrong here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862214/python-importerror-what-is-wrong-here)) but in vain thus far. My current system Path variable includes the location of my python script; the environment PATH variable includes the location of the Anaconda libraries: "...\Anaconda2\Library\bin;". Does this appear correct?
- Many solutions refer to circular dependencies, which I do not believe I have in the one module.
- Other solutions are to do with the name of the script. Mine is named 'my_solution', so I do not believe this is an issue.
- My sklearn folder can be found in \AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\sklearn

I have recently uninstalled a standalone Python application. I have also reinstalled Anadonda and the scikit-learn, numpy and scipy packages multiple times.

I am using Python 2.7.11 through Anaconda 2.5.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` check each path for module. If it get module in first path, it will not check second entry in `PYTHONPATH`. So please check each path in your `PYTHONPATH`, if you have other `.py` file `sklearn.py` then it start importing from there. This file might be not have `neighbours`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the American spelling of neighbours, i.e.

```
from sklearn import neighbors
```